# NSString to uint8_t doesn't match

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to convert an NSString to uint8_t.  The problem I'm having is that the NSString and the resulting uint8_t variables do not match.  Here is some example code:

```
NSLog(@"Key now: %@", key);
NSData* keyData = [key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

const uint8_t *plainBuffer = (const uint8_t*)[data bytes];
size_t plainBufferSize = strlen((char *) plainBuffer);
NSLog(@"Plain buffer: %s", plainBuffer);

NSData* testData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes: plainBuffer length:plainBufferSize];
NSString* testString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: testData encoding:   NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Test string: %@", testString);
```

And example output:

```
Key now: 9iIWBpf5R6yu5pJ93l218RsMdWBLidXt
Plain buffer: 9iIWBpf5R6yu5pJ93l218RsMdWBLidXtMdWBLidXt
Test string: 9iIWBpf5R6yu5pJ93l218RsMdWBLidXtMdWBLidXt
```

Clearly its the NSData -> uint8_t step thats going wrong, but I don't know why!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't `- [NSString dataUsingEncoding:]` discard the terminating NUL byte? Why don't you simply use `- [NSString UTF8String]` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `strlen()` to get the size of an `NSData*`. That's not going to work. The `NSData*` isn't NUL-terminated. So you're getting garbage on the end.

Don't use `strlen()`. Just ask the `NSData*` for its size directly.

Alternatively, don't use `NSData*` at all and just ask for `[key UTF8String]`. That hands back a NUL-terminated `const char *`.

Comment: Ah, so basically what I thought :) Another argument against redundancy.

Comment: Both excellent points, switching to [key UTF8String] did the job, thanks!